# Share props between components in NextJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js

Projects file structure looks like this:

```
components
├─homepage
│ ├─index.jsx
├─location
│ ├─index.jsx
pages
│ ├─location
│ │ ├─[id].jsx
│ ├─presentation
│ │ ├─[id].jsx
│ ├─_app.jsx
│ ├─index.jsx
functions
├─dataFetch.js
```

`pages/index.jsx` has `getInitialProps()` with data fetching function within. I need to share api fetch result data to `pages/location/[id].jsx` and `pages/presentation/[id].jsx`.

My solution to this problem was to start using redux (which I will need not only for this case).
However, it makes a problem with pages rendering props on first load of the website.

For example, if I go to `http://localhost:3000` - it will work just fine, as data is fetched in `pages/index.jsx`.
But if I go to `http://localhost:3000/location/12345` - there will be no fetched data, because I don't call `getInitialProps()` on that page.

Is my way to resolving this problem using redux is correct? And if so, where exactly should I fetch data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say add a AppWrapper which renders children inside a context provider https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext. And put that in the _app.jsx

_app.jsx would also be the place if you are going for Redux to fetch the data.